# Remove appended elements in mouseleave (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an image to pop up (a larger version of it is displayed) when the mouse is hovered over the image and remove the appended elements when mouse leaves the image. Here's the relevant code:

```
var imgs;
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
    $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
    imgs = `<div id="preview"> <img src="images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')}"
                alt="${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}"/>`;
    var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('city')}
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('taken')}
                </p></div>`;
    imgs += info;
    $("body").append($(imgs));
    // console.log(imgs);
})

$(document).on("mousemove", function( event ) {
    $("#preview").css("left", event.pageX);
    $("#preview").css("top", event.pageY);
});
 
$(document).on("mouseleave", '.gallery li', function() {
    // $("body").remove();
    // $("body").find('img').removeClass("gray");
    // $("body").remove($(imgs));
    alert('hello');
})
```

```
#preview {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: #424242;
}
.gray {
     filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```
<main class="container">     
    <ul class="gallery">
    </ul>
          
</main>
```

`Mousleave` is not working as I'd expect. Instead `div`s are appended to body. While debugging I found that `mouseleave` gets executed when mouse moves (alert message pops up on every mouse move). Also, the popped up image under the mouse cursor doesn't change. It stays the same.
What I want to to pop the appended elements during `mouseenter`, such that every time mouse is hovered over image, append and pop happens on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

The output shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R28eY.jpg). `div` is for some reason not obeying event coordinates. Images show up at the bottom.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this code.

Comment: You can try with `mouseout` instead of `mouseleave` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event they behave differently. Also, why not just remove the div with id `preview` instead of storing the imgs var globally?

Comment: I tried with `mouseout` also. I see a similar behviour. Tried with this also `$(".preview").remove();`, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi do you need something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/2qdvyh1x/) ?

Comment: Your answer is the best I've got. But `div` doesn't seem to obey event coordinates. The image is lined up at the bottom. See the cursor. It shows like this https://imgur.com/a/MjoHIz2

Comment: did you added that div which i have added in jsfiddle i.e :`<div class="images_append"></div>` ? because in fiddle as you can see that doesn't happen its moving with mouse..

Comment: Yeah, I added that. Otherwise image won't even appear.

Comment: @Swati I've created a new thread with all info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113896/div-not-obeying-event-coordinates. Does `li` impose some restriction on placement of `div` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` has `id="preview"` so you need `id selector` `#` to get element.

Use `$('#preview').remove()` it will work.

Or you can add `class="preview"` in then `$(".preview").remove();` will work.

**Edit** added offset to `top` & `left` so when mouse moves it won't flicker.

Try it below. Added `class="preview"` and used `class selector` `.` as `$('.preview')`.

```js
var xOffset = 3;
var yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
  $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
  imgs = `<div id="preview" class="preview"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=328&g=1"
                alt="k"/>`;
  var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                </p></div>`;
  imgs += info;
  $("body").append($(imgs));
  // console.log(imgs);
})

$(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
 $("#preview")
            .css("top",(event.pageY + xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(event.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", '.gallery li', function() {
  $(".preview").remove();
})
```

```css
#preview {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  /* display: none; */
  background-color: #424242;
}

.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=48&g=1" alt="K" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't seem to make a difference. With this change, the pop stops working. Since `mousleave` is executed on every mouse move.

Comment: `mouseenter` will also executed on every mouse move. Added offset so while mouse move it won't flicker. Please try with `Run code snippet`.

Comment: I want it to take some action only when mouse leaves that li element (which is img in this case).

Comment: You can add your action into `mouseleave`.

Comment: What Peter suggested seems to be working but the div positions seems off. Here's the output that I see imgur.com/a/237EFmw. The image is inserted below the footer and not where mouse is being pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `index()` of the `li` element that the image exists in, to the `id` of the `.preview` element. In addition you could use jQuery [`Deffered`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and [`.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (this is optional). Below is an example.

```
var df = $.Deferred();
var xOffset = 3;
var yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
  $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
  let imgs = `<div class="preview"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6RvS.png?s=328&g=1"
                alt="k"/>`;
  var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}
                </p></div>`;
  imgs += info;
  let imgObj = $(imgs);
  imgObj.attr("id", "preview-"+$(this).index());
  $("body").append(imgObj );
  df.resolve( true );
});
 
$.when( df ).done(function ( v ) {
  if(v) {
      $(document).on("mousemove", '.gallery li', function(event) {
          $("#preview-"+$(this).index())
            .css("top",(event.pageY + xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(event.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
      });

      $(document).on("mouseleave", '.gallery li', function() {
          $("#preview-"+$(this).index()).remove();
      });
  }
});
```

Here is an example.

```js
var df = $.Deferred();
const xOffset = 3;
const yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li img', function(event) {
  $(event.target).addClass("gray");
  let alttext = $(event.target).attr('alt');
  let imgs = `<div class="preview"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200"
                alt="k"/>`;
  var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${alttext}
                'City': ${alttext}
                'Date Taken': ${alttext}
                </p></div>`;
  imgs += info;
  let imgObj = $(imgs);
  imgObj.attr("id", "preview-"+$(event.target).parent().index());
  $("body").append(imgObj );
  df.resolve( true );
});
 
$.when( df ).done(function( v ) {
  if(v) {
      $(document).on("mousemove", '.gallery li img', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          $("#preview-"+$(event.target).parent().index())
            .css("top",(event.pageY + xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(event.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .css("display","block");
      });

      $(document).on("mouseleave", '.gallery li img', function(event) {
          $("#preview-"+$(event.target).parent().index()).remove();
      });
  }
});
```

```css
[id^="preview-"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #424242;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 11rem; // you may use percentage e.g. 20% or viewport units here e.g. 10vw
}
[id^="preview-"] img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/70" alt="K" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know about `when` and `Deferred`. This seems to be doing the job. The position of pop-up image seems off in my case. They show up at the bottom. Is there a better way to display the image such that mouse pointer stays at the center of the image, and image is fully visible. In your snippet, image is displayed at the bottom when mouse is hovered.

Comment: @kl_divergence check the edited snippet. This way the image is displayed right next to the ***hovered*** image. In the update it is crucial that the element is added one more `CSS` attribute that changes the visibility of the element (`display: block`) when the positioning has finished.

Comment: This change broke the functionality for me. Earlier everything was working as expected, the images were showing up at the bottom, now hovering functionality doesn't work. Why did you change to Arrow function here ?

Comment: I have reverted to your previous snippet because it was working. Here's the output that I see https://imgur.com/a/237EFmw. The image is inserted below the footer and not where mouse is being pointed at.

Comment: @kl_divergence i will edit my answer to change it. Does the position of the image need to rollback or it is ok? If the previous snippet had issues in positioning the #preview element, then you should have CSS that override the CSS in the snippet.

Comment: Once the mouse leaves the li, it should remove the preview class. I want to do all by JS, so you can do whatever you require. I tried different settings to mange, but somehow div tag doesn't obey event coordinate positions.

Comment: @kl_divergence please review the edited snippet. It is a complete rollback except the fact that in `CSS` it is set `display: none` and changes after the element is positioned to `display: block`. That small fix is needed in order for the element to be shown exactly after it is positioned.

Comment: Please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113896/div-not-obeying-event-coordinates. I've properly outlined the issue. I'm using your working code.

Comment: I've added some extra part which I didn't mention here. Does `li` pose some restriction on the position of new `div` tag ?