# `div` not obeying event coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My current code is (courtesy [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560539/peter-darmis)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '', //contains a list of paths
        data: { get_param: 'value' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            element = data[0];
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $(".gallery").append($(`<li><img src="${`images/square/${element.path}`}" 
                alt="${element.title}"id="${element.path}"city="${element.city}"
                taken="${element.taken}"/></li>`));
            });
        },
    });
});

var df = $.Deferred();
const xOffset = 3;
const yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
    $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
    var imgs = `<div class="preview"> <img src="images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')}"
                alt="${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}"/>`;
    var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}<br>
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('city')}<br>
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('taken')}
                </p></div>`;
    imgs += info;
    // $(".images_append").html($(imgs));
    let imgObj = $(imgs);
    imgObj.attr("id", "preview-"+$(this).index());
    $("body").append(imgObj );
    df.resolve( true );
});

$.when( df ).done(function ( v ) {
    if(v) {
        $(document).on("mousemove", '.gallery li', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#preview-"+$(this).index())
              .css("top",((event.pageY) + xOffset)+"px")
              .css("left",((event.pageX) + yOffset)+"px");
        });
  
        $(document).on("mouseout", '.gallery li', function() {
            $("#preview-"+$(this).index()).remove();
            $(this).find('img').removeClass("gray");
        });
    }
  });
```

Basically when mouse is hovered, load up a bigger image, and when it is removed, remove the `preview` class.

Currently the output shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtazV.jpg). Images show up at the bottom for some reason and not following event coordinates from `mousemove`.

Here's the CSS

```
#preview {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    /* display: none; */
    background-color: #424242;
    /* z-index: 9999; */
    /* display: flex; */
}
#preview p {
    color: white; 
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.gray {
     filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

I'm basically not touching HTML. So it's a simple HTML page.

Can you please suggest why is it not following these coordinates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to slightly change your `CSS`. In the code you posted the URL's of the images are not working, but with the following `CSS` you will see the `#preview-...` element.

I also need to explain better the changes that are applied in the snippet at the end of the answer.

**First:** thing that it is changed is that the `id` of the container element displayed on hover is not `preview` but `preview-1, preview-2, ...` where `0,1,2,...,n` is the index of the `li` element where the image is located. You can understand why this is done, it is ideal to have `unique` identification of elements. It works better when you have to handle those elements with `Javascript`.

**Second:** To work using `$.Deffered` is optional you could skip it if you want (check the last code snippet). But since it is used in this paradigm then it is needed that the `CSS` of the `[id^="preview-"]` elements to have `display: none` and to switch to `display: block` only after it is correctly positioned to the `DOM`. That is why there is this small addition in `Javascript`.

```
$("#preview-"+$(this).index())
 .css("top",((event.pageY) + xOffset)+"px")
 .css("left",((event.pageX) + yOffset)+"px")
 .css("display","block");
```

The above was needed because without this sometimes the `[id^="preview-"]` element appeared in the bottom of the page (the similar effect you are currently facing).

**PS:** If there is any other `CSS` that is included in your actual project, and the elements of the example are affected, then those values have to be overridden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prajjwal1/uploads/master/data.json',
        data: { get_param: 'value' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            element = data[0];
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $(".gallery").append($(`<li><img src="${`images/square/${element.path}`}" 
                alt="${element.title}"id="${element.path}"city="${element.city}"
                taken="${element.taken}"/></li>`));
            });
        },
    });
});

var df = $.Deferred();
const xOffset = 3;
const yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
    $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
    var imgs = `<div class="preview"> <img src="images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')}"
                alt="${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}"/>`;
    var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}<br>
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('city')}<br>
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('taken')}
                </p></div>`;
    imgs += info;
    // $(".images_append").html($(imgs));
    let imgObj = $(imgs);
    imgObj.attr("id", "preview-"+$(this).index());
    $("body").append(imgObj );
    df.resolve( true );
});

$.when( df ).done(function ( v ) {
    if(v) {
        $(document).on("mousemove", '.gallery li', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#preview-"+$(this).index())
              .css("top",((event.pageY) + xOffset)+"px")
              .css("left",((event.pageX) + yOffset)+"px")
              .css("display","block");
        });
  
        $(document).on("mouseout", '.gallery li', function() {
            $("#preview-"+$(this).index()).remove();
            $(this).find('img').removeClass("gray");
        });
    }
  });
```

```css
[id^="preview-"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #424242;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 11rem; // you may use percentage e.g. 20% or viewport units here e.g. 10vw
}
[id^="preview-"] img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
  </ul>
</main>
```

Same example without `$.Deffered`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prajjwal1/uploads/master/data.json',
    data: {
      get_param: 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      element = data[0];
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        $(".gallery").append($(`<li><img src="${`images/square/${element.path}`}" 
                alt="${element.title}"id="${element.path}"city="${element.city}"
                taken="${element.taken}"/></li>`));
      });
    },
  });
});


const xOffset = 3;
const yOffset = 3;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
  $(this).find('img').addClass("gray");
  var imgs = `<div class="preview"> <img src="images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')}"
                alt="${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}"/>`;
  var info = `<p>
                'Title': ${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}<br>
                'City': ${$(this).find('img').attr('city')}<br>
                'Date Taken': ${$(this).find('img').attr('taken')}
                </p></div>`;
  imgs += info;
  let imgObj = $(imgs);
  imgObj.attr("id", "preview-" + $(this).index());
  $("body").append(imgObj);
});


$(document).on("mousemove", '.gallery li', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#preview-" + $(this).index())
    .css("top", ((event.pageY) + xOffset) + "px")
    .css("left", ((event.pageX) + yOffset) + "px");
});

$(document).on("mouseout", '.gallery li', function() {
  $("#preview-" + $(this).index()).remove();
  $(this).find('img').removeClass("gray");
});
```

```css
[id^="preview-"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #424242;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 11rem; // you may use percentage e.g. 20% or viewport units here e.g. 10vw
}

[id^="preview-"] img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.gray {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried CSS from your previous snippet. It didn't seem to work, but with the changes now. It seems to be working.

Comment: @kl_divergence Good i am not changing anything in any example. :)

Comment: I checked it. Your changes were not clear to me earlier, now they are. I was trying, maybe I would be missing something. Thanks though.

Comment: @kl_divergence there are many times that we can simply miss something. For me this mostly happens when i am tired. There are many times that i don't actually read the questions correctly, or "miss something" ... :)